# Window with role client has no controls using MSAALayer

Tags: c#, winapi, controls, findwindow

I am using MSAALayer interface to get the controls of some window. I looked up in the "Inspect.exe" with MSAAlayer interface, basically the window have textbox, check box and two buttons, but! It is not possible to find this buttons inside this window and this window have the role "Client". What does it mean? How can i find the text box and button controls inside a window that has a role "Client"? I also tried to access the controls inside with WinApi, but `EnumChildWindows` was unable to find any controls inside. Can someone explain, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean not possible to find? Does IAccessible::get_accChildCount() say there are no children? Also since you are using C#, why not use UI Automation instead of MSAA?

Comment: @andlabs hello. IThe problem is the following, i am using the simple program made on firefox engine (gecko). On some sites it is possible to select the (ssl) certificate to use it instead of login/pass. So basically there will appear a window called "User Identification Request" with "ok" "cancel" buttons, and a combobox where you can select the certificate. By not possible to find i mean that, in inspector i can find this window, but! It is impossible to find the child controls, buttons, combobox, and text labels. Inspector tool display that there is 7 child objects

Comment: @andlabs but i can only view the 'header'. Actually i think i will make some screenshots that will clarify this a bit. I tried UI Automation in `Inspect` tool, result is the same. Also, if the same window appear from actual firefox browser i can find ALL the controls using Inspect tool no matter MSAA/Ui Auto. Also the program that uses the engine is managed, could it be that this causes such bugs?

Comment: Please do; that would help explain what's going on. It's probably a bug in Firefox if some dialog isn't properly made accessible.

Comment: @andlabs its not on firefox actually, it is on 3rd party application that uses firefox engine. This application is written on managed code

Comment: @andlabs i will try my best to explain, so [first_screenshot](http://plasmon.rghost.ru/private/7mvzTN94t/e3cee1c73ea0096ae9354e8e914a19fb/image.png)
here i took the firefox browser, and i went on following url: https://webmail.peds.umaryland.edu/UPIRootCa.crt
which gave me the popup dialog window, for installing root certificate in my firefox profile. On the right in "Inspect" tool you can see the name of this dialog
'"Загрузка Сертификата" окно' - That means '"Downloading Certificate" window'.

Comment: @andlabs Here is another screenshot of the Inspect with properties of this window generated by mozilla

[here](http://higgs.rghost.ru/private/8SQzwbjZm/3dc61dc70621886d78abb7056c738f4f/image.png) you can see that this window have a lot of child elements - buttons ("OK","CANCEL (Отмена)"), textboxes, etc.
And also in the ancestor property you can see that this window ancestor is mozilla.Ok. Same url i'm opening in the 3rd party program based on firefox engine (It's called zennoposter, its a tool for seo automatiation)

Comment: @andlabs Here you can see on this (this is same window generated by Zennoposter) [screenshot](http://higgs.rghost.ru/private/8wLfQMMKX/bf9681f8c02487b5c55a859875e76ea0/image.png) Inspector cannot find any child elements inside!!! Also here is an Inspector window for zennoposter generated window with properties [screen](http://tau.rghost.ru/8Yf5xPJJf/image.png) As you can see here, the ancestor is no one basically ("Рабочий Стол" панель - stands for Desktop Panel)

Comment: @andlabs So final image:

Mozilla Firefox Generated window is on the left, Zennoposter generated window is on the right

[first](http://tau.rghost.ru/private/7TwSl9GPk/c3a02c400267ffa0d0c8434d6a315940/image.png)
[second](http://higgs.rghost.ru/private/7XQb4nysQ/59caf2d685ab3e80639a82fb8dc6620b/image.png)

As you can see firefox can successfully find child controls in Mozilla's Window, and cannot find anything in Zennoposter's case
Can this be because of the Zennoposter "Downloading Center" Window have no ancestor?

Comment: @andlabs Also, Zennoposter is written on c#, but uses the unmanaged firefox gecko engine. Can this be the case too? I'm out of ideas

Comment: All right. I'm not sure, apart from it being a potential problem with the program in question. You'll have to file a bug report with them. Sorry :/